# How do I access "node.type.kind" of TypeElement?

Tags: typescript

I'm using the TypeScript API.

I have a `ts.TypeElement` that I know has a `.type.kind` accessor, however when I try to access it I get a type error.

I've been looking through the TypeScript API for a `.hasTypeNode()` guard, but I can't find anything.

I'm specifically trying to access this property on members of a `ts.isInterfaceDeclaration()`.

```
import * as ts from 'typescript';

const input = `
interface Options {
  /** something cool */
  key: boolean;
}
`;

const source = ts.createSourceFile('index.ts', input, ts.ScriptTarget.ES5);
ts.forEachChild(source, node => {
  if (ts.isInterfaceDeclaration(node)) {
    // member is set to any here but if you remove it
    // there's a type  error when accessing member.type
    node.members.forEach((member: any) => {
      console.log(member.type.kind); // 128
    });
  }
});
```

[TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5xugZlCI4DkMAnmAKaoDGUwYMBA3ALABQrlEAdqvMJ2AFd4AXjgADVnxhkoWZJTJwA8nWBd0Ab1Zw4AegRJUeMjAAWfAOZwOEADaJd2uAGsyxAFxwARhDtlknMwsAL6sYkHs6vBGAlAKcKKYAHTU-tIAyhCxCgBiwLZkABQEfAAmZAAeSZgEADRwfIIw9cnp1LQwACrIUBYmSQCi6QCsAJRByVjQA-KmAMLmtqWFMXFk9ZwQ5QkAfHBaLDrAWHCFycCoAJKc0rLyZAAiZJS2PcgwapyFm%20Wjo-tOHS6XRwEBkEBeGQNdCoEwYCAoTjEOCmGSKLxCBonYhZOBQcEQABuimAMEBehBZjRBHQyAwpEUcBkuCgcAA7qjOChKApUKhLKDwZCoNUGeSfmQkmCITJUEkplAZpRTIVCtLhf9hHsDjpddZ1H4krYIBY1UKZKLyElnGVxhS4ABGABMAA5ycFxk5QiFxkA)

[image]

> Property 'type' does not exist on type 'TypeElement'.

Comment: Please include a [mcve] with the full error message in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I created a custom guard:

```
function hasTypeNode(
  node: ts.TypeElement & { type?: ts.TypeNode }
): node is ts.TypeElement & { type: ts.TypeNode } {
  const type = node.type;
  return !!type;
}
```